# Drop constraint in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that the first thing I want it to do is to delete all existing data in 2 tables (the procedure is to recalculate all the data in those tables and its easier to start from scratch)

Is it ok/safe to drop the FK constraint and truncate the table and then recreate the constraint? Or maybe you have some other idea?

It's working with delete but its taking too long and sometimes fails because of full memory.

```
ALTER TABLE t_matrix360circles
DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_t_matrix360Circles_t_matrix360]

TRUNCATE TABLE t_matrix360circles
TRUNCATE TABLE t_matrix360

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[t_matrix360Circles] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_t_matrix360Circles_t_matrix360] 
        FOREIGN KEY([matrix360Id])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[t_matrix360] ([matrix360ID])
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[t_matrix360Circles] 
    CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_t_matrix360Circles_t_matrix360]
GO
```

Thanks

Comment: If you truncate the 'many' side first, can't you keep the constraint?

Comment: what do you mean 'many' side? this is what i get when try to truncate- Cannot truncate table 't_matrix360' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Comment: Have you considered dropping the table, and then recreating it? You're kind of doing that if you truncate and remove the constraints anyway.

Comment: @MarkKaptsan you should empty t_matrix360circles before emptying the t_matrix360

Comment: @iDevlop - No. SQL Server doesn't care if the table referencing the constraint is empty or even if the constraint is disabled. Just the existence of it will prevent `TRUNCATE`.

Comment: And yeah if you just want to nuke all data in those tables from scratch efficiently you can use your `TRUNCATE` approach. You should probably have everything in a transaction though. Also you should look at module signing to avoid having to grant elevated permissions to the executor of the proc

Comment: Or at least use try catch, this way you can clean up and properly restore your constraints on errors